# Gzip -c over pipe matter?

Tags: gzip

I saw sometime 2 ways of writting: with and without `-c`

Do the 2 following case output the same and have equal speed ?

```
mysqldump -u root dbname | gzip > test.sql
mysqldump -u root dbname | gzip -c > test.sql
```

What about continous pipe?

```
mysqldump -u root dbname | gzip | anotherprogram
```

Thanks for clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to `man gzip`:
>   "*If no files are specified, or if a file name is "-", the standard input is compressed to the standard output.*"

In all your cases you piping source stream to `gzip`'s STDIN without specifying content to compress as a source file. In these cases `gzip` sends compressed stream to STDOUT by default that makes `-c` option useless/redundant.

The `-c` option is useful when you calling `gzip` as `gzip -c sourceFile` so in this case instead of
**compressing sourceFIle+adding extension GZ+deleting sourceFile**
it will send compressed stream to STDOUT and won't delete *sourceFile*.
For example:

```
gzip -c sourceFile | anotherProgram
```

Comment: Ty for clarify!

Comment: Also, I suggest, "speed" is not really a primary-concern here:  you simply want to find something that works!  There is no appreciable "overhead" associated with any of these possible ways to do it.  Also note that the running time of *any* alternative will vary naturally from one run to the next, perhaps giving the impression that "one or the other one is 'faster,'" when in fact this is not so.

Comment: I don't think `gzip` decides the output mode based on `>` redirect, but rather if the input files are *a)* specified as CLI parameters or *b)* piped in using `|`. So the `-c` would be mandatory in this case `gzip -c file1 file2 > foo.gz`, but not for this `cat file1 file2 | gzip > foo.gz`.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík I didn't said "gzip decides the output mode based on `>` redirect", but I used phrase that ended with:  "*in your use case*". `-c` isn't mandatory if one want to compress file1 and file2 (`gzip file1 file2`) separately even it's CLI. According to `man gzip` all `-c` is doing is: *"Write  output  on standard output; keep original file**s** unchanged."*

Comment: Well, your first sentence states that `-c` has no effect since he is using stdout redirect. You are right about that gzip defaults to stdout in his use case, but not for the reason you wrote.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík I added excerpt from `man gzip` to clarify the reason why `gzip` ignores `-c` option in cases like redirect/pipe where no source file(s) are specified. I hope that's what you mention.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that it does not matter if there is redirect or pipe *behind* the `gzip` command. What matters is that there is pipe *before* it. I was not talking about the trailing `|` but about the leading one. I probably didn't make this clear, but if you reread my comments with this in mind it should make sense. Otherwise I am sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík No bothering at all, I appreciate your clarification that make sense now and might be helpful for others. I updated my answer to avoid confuse with my previous wording.